# count with where clause and where condition should take from textBox

Tags: asp.net, ms-access-2007

How to count with where clause and where condition should take from textBox

```
select Count(SRNO) from [Visitor_Customer] where [month]= & me.textBox1.text
```

this code is not working

please help....

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
"select Count(SRNO) from [Visitor_Customer] where [month]= "& me.textBox1.text
```

Comment: You can't trust the contents of the text box, so you need prepared statements instead.  Just ask 'Bobby Tables'. This page may help: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.prepare.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1

Comment: Try this "select Count(SRNO) from [Visitor_Customer] where [month]= '"+ me.textBox1.text +"'" OR
"select Count(SRNO) from [Visitor_Customer] where [month]= '"& me.textBox1.text &"'"

Comment: @megha please check this URL, it will help you to accept the answer or provide me email id, i will explain how to accept answer
http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23138/how-to-accept-the-answer-on-stack-overflow